# Django update query not saving on rare occasions, with no error

Tags: django, azure

Whether I run model.save() or model.update() it works 99% of the time. About 1% of the time the save fails silently, all values are logged and correct, all exceptions caught, no errors whatsoever, just the value did not actually save to the server.

When running the server locally I noticed this happened frequently when increasing load and executing many queries quickly, but on the production server it happens much more rarely (Because the production server is much more powerful than my local server).

It's like some update queries get skipped under heavier load, note I don't think it's a deadlock because pyodbc logs those for me. The db is in azure. How can I debug this further? Is it possible there's some kind of azure db query error that's not being logged to my end?query result is always success, no exceptions triggered. Thanks

```
filters = json.loads(request.POST.get('filters'))
table_name = request.POST.get('table')
table = eval(table_name)
fields_values = json.loads(request.POST.get('fields_values'))
row = table.objects.get(**filters)
result = ""
try:
    for field in fields_values:
      setattr(row, field, fields_values[field])

      row.save()
      result = "success"
    except Exception as e:
      print(e)
return JsonResponse({"result": result})
```

Comment: Show us a Minimal, Reproducible Example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @EneP Added, sorry... Note my current method is using eval() to determine/query model but I've also done with hardcoding the model and setting the fields and have had the same thing happen.

Comment: You need to find output of `print(e)` in your logs..

Comment: @Kedar There's no errors, I actually have a db logger setup as well and there has never been an error when this issue occurred which is the entire problem, it just fails silently. An exception doesn't trigger at all, because I have a result string "success" that's set after row.save() that always prints at the end of the function.

Comment: Then the request/thread/server is getting killed after call to row.save() but before hitting the exception block I guess. Add a log line after `row.save()` to confirm

Comment: @Kedar Don't think so because I have more code that's triggered by the success response, which is saving the value into my "history" table (which stores all the previous values of the field). The history table query will run afterwards and save successfully what actually led me to finding this bug because I would have had no way of knowing save wasn't working on rare occasions since there are no exceptions

Comment: what database? maybe database is returning success response before writting result to disk?